# Spring upgrade issue - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have upgraded my spring boot from 2.2.6.RELEASE to 2.7.0.
After the upgrade , i am getting ClassNotFoundException when i start the application.
I tried with 2.6.6 but result is same.

My pom file looks like

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Exception :

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveElasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
                   
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
                  
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
                 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
                    ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/xcontent/XContentParser
                .....
                    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
                    ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.xcontent.XContentParser
                    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
                    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
                    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
                    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could solve the issue. In the parent pom had elastic search version was given explicitly. Once i remove the given version error has gone and application works fine.